# How to mosaic multiple rasters (MODIS data) in R programming

Tags: raster, r, merge, modis, mosaic

I've four tiles of MOD16A2 dataset, I want to mosaic them using following script in R.

```
filez <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = ".tif") 

    r.list <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(filez)){  
    
        r.list[[i]] <- raster(filez[i])  
    } 
    m <- do.call(merge, r.list)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different resolution
```

When I explore further r.list I got:

```
    > r.list
[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3150, 6486, 20430900  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.003174517, 0.003174517  (x, y)
extent     : 57.73503, 78.32494, 30.00027, 40  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : MOD16A2.A2002001.h23v05.006.2017075173946_ET.tif 
names      : MOD16A2.A2002001.h23v05.006.2017075173946_ET 
values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2896, 4654, 13477984  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.003453574, 0.003453574  (x, y)
extent     : 53.20889, 69.28182, 19.99845, 30  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : MOD16A2.A2002001.h23v06.006.2017075173048_ET.tif 
names      : MOD16A2.A2002001.h23v06.006.2017075173048_ET 
values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)


[[3]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3292, 7275, 23949300  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.003037283, 0.003037283  (x, y)
extent     : 69.28203, 91.37827, 30.00126, 40  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : MOD16A2.A2002001.h24v05.006.2017075173934_ET.tif 
names      : MOD16A2.A2002001.h24v05.006.2017075173934_ET 
values     : 1, 32766  (min, max)


[[4]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3010, 5111, 15384110  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.003322226, 0.003322226  (x, y)
extent     : 63.85067, 80.83056, 20.0001, 30  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : MOD16A2.A2002001.h24v06.006.2017075171525_ET.tif 
names      : MOD16A2.A2002001.h24v06.006.2017075171525_ET 
values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

I got, my rasters have different scales, dimensions etc; that why I'm getting this error.

How can I make mosaic of these rasters in R?

Comment: You need to use `projectRaster` to make sure all the rasters are on the same aligned coordinate system, then you can use `merge` or `mosaic`.

Comment: @Spacedman how I use projectRaster dear?

Comment: Read the documentation for `projectRaster`? Sorry for not providing a complete solution but sometimes I only have time to try and suggest something that if you do a bit of work might get you to the answer. It also saves us time if you can provide reproducible examples in your questions, otherwise we spend time making data to run through `projectRaster` and `mosaic` to make sure it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a little late for this to be answered. Nevertheless, here is an answer for someone with the same problem/request. I would highly encourage you to try the `MODIStsp` package in `R` ([see this page for installation and use](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODIStsp/vignettes/MODIStsp.html)). Once installed, you can run: `MODIStsp()` in `R` and a GUI will appear in your web-browser. The steps are the following.

1. In Product and layers: Select both the MODIS product and layer you want to use (you can also select the product version and platform i.e. Terra or Aqua)
2. In Spatial/Temporal options, select the date range for your images and the MODIS tiles you need. If you select more than one tile, it will automatically perform a mosaic of the images. You can also add a shapefile (in geographic coordinates) of your region of interest. In these options you can also select your output product coordinate system. I would suggest using WGS84 Geographic system i.e. EPSG:4326. Select "user defined" projection, and under projection name put 4326. You can even resample the data chosing an specific spatial resolution. Note that a resampling occurs when reprojecting the image from Sinusoidal to Geographic coordinates, and thus you need to select the resampling method. Choose `near` for nearest neighbor (if the product has a qualitative variable e.g. land cover products) or `bilinear` for a bilinear interpolation (if the product has a continuous variable e.g. NDVI products).
3. Finally, in the Output Format and Folders, select the download method as http, place your user name and password from [NASA's EarthData](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/home). In the output options, you can select the output format, save the data as a rasterStack, among others. If you are downloading an specific product, you can select "Yes" in the "Apply Scale/Offset" so your final product has the corresponding values i.e. it will apply the scale factor to the data. Select an output folder where the processed images will be stored and an output folder for the original HDF files.